# How do I get a substring from a cell in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**How do I get a substring from a cell in Google Apps Script?**

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a website.
I've already got the whole HTML code 
and put it into a cell (thou it could be better put into a String variable)

I'm stuck in a simpler task: 
How do I get the part of that cell/string I'm interested in,
(since I know it is always located in the same position/offset)

I tried `string.substring(offset, length)`
but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?
Help appreciated.

Comment: More context (code) would help. Also, perhaps Stack Overflow would be a more suitable place for this question, since it is a programming question. There's a google-apps-script tag there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. My mistake.

The right usage of **substring** method is:

```
string.substring(starting-offset, ending-offset)
```

Here's the whole code. Already ready. Improvements may come later.

```
function Agrega_Valores_Actualizados() {
      var Libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var Hoja_0 = Libro.getSheets()[0];

      Hora = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-4', 'HH');

      if (Hora > 17) {
        Fecha_B3_Simple = Hoja_0.getRange("B3").getDisplayValue(); 
        Hoy_Form_Simple = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-4', 'dd-MM-yy');
        if (Fecha_B3_Simple != Hoy_Form_Simple) {
          //Inserta línea entre 3 y 4
          Hoja_0.insertRowAfter(3);

          //Copia línea 3 a la 4
          Linea3 = Hoja_0.getRange("B3:F3");
          Linea4 = Hoja_0.getRange("B4:F4");
          Linea3.copyTo(Linea4);
          F3 = Hoja_0.getRange("F3"); F3.setValue("=E3-E4");
          F4 = Hoja_0.getRange("F4"); F4.setValue("=E4-E5");

          //Borra contenido de celdas C3 y D3
          Valores_A_y_B_Linea3 = Hoja_0.getRange("C3:D3"); Valores_A_y_B_Linea3.clearContent();

          //Coloca fecha actual en celda B3
          Fecha_Linea3 = Hoja_0.getRange("B3"); Fecha_Linea3.setValue(Hoy_Form_Simple)

          //Busca Valor de Acciones en Página de Índice Bursátil
          var Contenido_URL = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.bancaynegocios.com/indice-bursatil-caracas/');
          var HTML = Contenido_URL.getContentText();

          P1 = HTML.search("Mercantil Servicios Financieros Clase A");
          C3 = Hoja_0.getRange("C3"); C3.setValue(HTML.substring(P1+110,P1+110+8));

          P2 = HTML.search("Mercantil Servicios Financieros Clase B");
          D3 = Hoja_0.getRange("D3"); D3.setValue(HTML.substring(P2+110,P2+110+8));
        }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `string.substring(offset, length)` works for me.

Let me show you:

```
var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var letra = "";
letra = alfabeto.substring(0,1);
```

Result:
letra = A